# unix shell ksh: if statement won't execute both parts

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

guys, my if statement is just executing the 1st part, the else is never executed, even if trying with nonexistent files, files with no reading access. it's so sad, I have been trying but nothing.
Would anyone suggest a trial for me please, Thanks.

```
#testing file to be read and display error messages:
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo="Error: Nonexistent or irregular file. "
  break
else
  echo Found
fi

if [ -r "$file" ]
then
  echo "No Reading access"
  break
else
  echo Reading Access
fi
```

Comment: Why do you have the `break` statements, what are you breaking from? Is there a surrounding loop that you aren't showing? P.S., it's 'nonexistent'

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how to edit my question nicely yet. :-)

Comment: highlight your code and hit CTRL+K or press the button that looks like this --> `{ }`

Comment: Yes, there is a loop, but the break statements doesn't execute as well... :-(

Comment: well if both the `-f` and the `-r` tests pass, then have the *true* case echo out what `$file` is. This information would prove useful to debug why the `else` clause is never hit. You could also try setting `file` right before your if-statement to be sure that nowhere in your loop is it getting set to something that actually exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#testing file to be read and display error messages:
if [ -f "$file" ];then
  echo "Error: Nonexistent or irregular file. "
else
  echo Found
fi

if [ -r "$file" ];then
  echo "No Reading access"
else
  echo Reading Access
fi
```